# Store JSON response of Array of dictionary in Realm

Tags: json, swift, database, realm

I am new to Realm. I want to store multiple array of dictionaries in Realm:

```
{
            "id": 18476525,
            "title": "Trump blames foreign countries for high drug prices",
            "show_id": 44900,
            "show_name": "FT News",
            "image": "http://app.storiyoh.com/image/eyJ3IjoyMDAsImgiOm51bGwsImltYWdlIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3N0b3JpeW9oLXByb2QtczMtYXNzZXRzLTE3dDR6dWZsa3ZvcGsuczMuYXAtc291dGgtMS5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tXC9zaG93c1wvMzc5NjEzODAxLmpwZyJ9",
            "duration": "00:06:21",
            "audio_file": "https://media.acast.com/ft-news/trumpblamesforeigncountriesforhighdrugprices/media.mp3",
            "like": "false",
            "like_count": 0,
            "comment_count": 0
        }
```

and show online and offline if it gets stored in Realm.

Comment: What did you try so far? Include the definition of your `Realm` model class that is represented by this JSON. You simply need to make your class conform to `Decodable` and you'll be able to parse the JSON, then store it in Realm just any other `Object` subclass instance.

Comment: I did so far like creating a model class and write to realm object

Comment: Then [edit] your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: This is lacking an [mcve] and appears to have been abandoned.